# How to remove XML comment element from a GhostDoc rule?

Tags: visual-studio, ghostdoc

I do not want to document the `<value>` element for C# properties. However, GhostDoc is configured to do exactly that. I thought it would be easy to remove it by visiting the configuration screen and just remove the element. But there is no button or right-click context menu to do it. Pressing `DEL` also does not work here. Any suggestions or ideas?

[image: Screenshot GhostDoc Configuration]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Serge B. here, I'm with SubMain (the GhostDoc company).

You want to remove the formula value (right column) in the `<value>` row - GhostDoc won't render the `<value>` section then.

Thanks!